# How should durations of time be displayed in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, time, spreadsheet, duration

I'm creating a report which display duration of time (in hours) between two points in time.

e.g.

Duration between 10:00 to 13:30 equals 3 hrs 30 minutes

This information is being saved into a spreadsheet (excel) in one "duration" column, titled "Duration (hrs)". The column needs to be sortable to allow sorting by longest duration, etc.

Should this be displayed as 3.5 or 3.30 using a numerical column format? Or as 03:30 using a time format? Is there a standard for this or purely down to preference?

Appreciate your thoughts!

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 2):

Note also that if you use "hh:mm" for your time format, that will just give you max 24, so even if it goes over several days, you won't see more than 24 hours. If you want the TOTAL number of hours, use "[hh]:mm"  to see e.g. 45:32

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably just down to preference - either method should work and be sortable

For a time format you can just subtract, e.g.

=B2-A2

or for decimal just multiply by 24

=(B2-A2)*24

Personally I think that time durations should be kept in time format.....